# How do you use ClassInitialize in a Coded UI Test?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm playing around with Coded UI Tests, writing some tests for the calc.exe application. I'm trying to use ClassInitialize to open the application so all my tests can run with the application open instead of each test having to open and close the application every time.

I found this from a Google search: http://www.codesmartnothard.com/CommentView,guid,f28e6205-1ac5-41f3-be0d-f84d7db5c79b.aspx but it's not useful. It would be awesome if this was actually all it took for it to work. What happens when I try it is the ClassInitialize function runs, the application opens, then it immediately closes before the 1st test attempts to run, so when the test runs the application isn't open any more and inevitably fails after some time of nothing happening.

How can I use ClassInitialize to open an application and KEEP IT OPEN for the tests to actually run?

When I have the following code, my tests run:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest1
{

  [TestMethod]
  public void CodedUITestMethod1()
  {
    UIMap.OpenCalc(); //Opens calc.exe
    UIMap.Click1(); //Clicks the "1" button
    UIMap.CloseCalc(); //Closes application
  }

  public TestContext TestContext
  {
    get
    {
      return testContextInstance;
    }
    set
    {
      testContextInstance = value;
    }
  }
  private TestContext testContextInstance;

  public static UIMap UIMap
  {
    get
    {
      if ((map == null))
      {
        map = new UIMap();
      }

      return map;
    }
  }

  private static UIMap map;
}
```

However, if I add this ClassInitialize method, and remove the call to OpenCalc in the TestMethod, it no longer works. The calculator opens, then immediately closes for whatever reason.

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
{
  Playback.Initialize();
  try
  {
    UIMap.OpenCalc();
  }
  finally
  {
    Playback.Cleanup();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the window closing I do this,
I use a web application but I think this will help.

First I declare the window using

```
window = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
```

then I set the property of the window

```
window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

**ClassInitilize is really messy** that way, I use it basically like a Constructor to declare some variables at the start of the test. Although there is alot of better ways to do what your trying to do.

If I were you I would make multiple [TestMethods] and make an orderedTest file, then specify which order you would like (ie. Put the openCalc() method first) like below.

```
[TestMethod]
  public void OpenCalc()
  {
      UIMap.OpenCalc(); //Opens calc.exe
  }


[TestMethod]
  public void CodedUITestMethod1()
  {
      UIMap.Click1(); //Clicks the "1" button
      UIMap.CloseCalc(); //Closes application
  }
```

Now right click your project and click new item, orderedTest. Then you can put the test methods in the order that you want, when you run the openCalc() method it should stay open for the remaining tests.

**Then basically in Test Explorer you just run the ordered test file instead of a test method.**

Comment: For some reason when I try this the calculator is closing right away after the `OpenCalc()` TestMethod runs, so when the `CodedUITestMethod1()` runs there is no calculator window to click in, after 20 seconds it times out and fails. And I do not have any TestInitialize or TestCleanup methods that are closing the calculator. It just closes automatically on its own after the 1st test completes.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the other test methods in the Test Explorer window?

Comment: hide? you could make a playlist with the ones you want and just select that, if your interested in hiding them so that you can right-click and select run all tests, dont do that.

That's bad, instead just use an orderedTest file.

Comment: I am using the orderedTest file. I just don't like how the Test Explorer window shows a bunch of tests in it when the ordered test is the only one that I ever actually run.

Comment: just make a playlist in TestExlporer and view that

Answer (score 1):

[ClassInitialize] is called once, before any tests are run. There is also an [AssemblyInitialize]that is called before any [ClassInitialize] methods are (or would be) run. The `UIMap map` field is normally a member of the class instance, not a static of the class and so the [ClassInitialize] method cannot access it. Your code declares `UIMap map` to be static which is likely to introduce problems in many test cases.

You wanted to start the application before running the tests, so that it can be used for all test cases. The `.testsettings` files allow start-up and clean-up scripts to be specified. You might start the application in such a script. To create a `.testsettings` file, right click on the solution in Solution Explorer, select Add => New Item. You will also have to select the `.testsettings` file via Menu => Test.

Comment: declaring the UIMap as static works perfectly fine as long as I call `UIMap.OpenCalc()` & `UIMap.CloseCalc()` inside of each TestMethod

Comment: @Nick it may work when you are "*playing around with Coded UI Tests*" but the UI Map acts as a cache into the windows and controls on the screen. As child windows of an application more complex than the calculator come and go, you are likely to get errors because the cached values refer to no-longer-existing controls. Relying on techniques that happen to work on a simple application like the calculator may cause problems when trying with bigger applications.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not I use a static property, the window is closing every time the function that it opens in is finished running.